# No Count function on Python on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, nameerror

When I try to use the 'list.count' function on my raspberry Pi it comes up with

```
   Name Error: name 'count' is not defined
```

Is there any thing I can do about it? Thank you in advance for any help. I am using Python. I am just starting out with Python and in my tutorial it states

```
   >>>count(seq,'a')
```

With 'seq' being a sequence of letters that I entered earlier. I expect it is meant to count the number of 'a's in the sequence.453

Thank you all very much for your quick responses and answers, I have now fixed the problem. This was my first ever online question that I asked so thank you again. The second answer by Markus Unterwaditzer finally solved the problem with 'seq.count('a')'

Also thanks to DSM for finding the tutorial and explaining why I had my problem. Everything works now and I am back to learning my first computer language.

Comment: What language is it? and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Can you try len(list)?

Comment: @JasonSperske: The `list.count()` method doesn't necessarily return the length of the list, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: What does `print type(list)` output?

Comment: Your tutorial is wrong, or you have misread it. Is it online? Can you post a link to it?

Comment: http://www.pasteur.fr/formation/infobio/python/ch01.html is the link to the tutorial. How would I do it instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah.  The magic in the tutorial is in the

```
from string import *
```

line, which is bad practice.  It imports everything from the string module into scope, including the function `string.count`:

```
>>> print string.count.__doc__
count(s, sub[, start[,end]]) -> int

    Return the number of occurrences of substring sub in string
    s[start:end].  Optional arguments start and end are
    interpreted as in slice notation.
```

`count` is also a method of strings, so you can write

```
>>> 'aaa'.count('a')
3
```

which is generally preferred.  In modern Python, the `string` module doesn't even *have* a `count` function.

Answer (score 1):

`I expect it is meant to count the number of 'a's in the sequence`

Depending on what `list` is, that's probably not the correct syntax. If `list` is a string you can do this:

```
>>>a = "hello"
>>>a.count('h')
1
>>>a.count('l')
2
```

Works the same for a "list":

```
>>>a = ['h','e','l','l','o']
>>>a.count('l')
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> seq = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
>>> seq.count('a')
2
>>> type(seq) is list  # the reason it's mentioned as list.count
True
>>> list.count(seq, 'a')  # the same thing, but nobody does it like that
2
```